# What is the official etiquette on answering a question twice?

Tags: discussion, answers, etiquette, faq-proposed, multiple-answers

When is it okay to post two answers to one question?

Comment: See also [Two Answers, One Question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/28471/163250) | [Can a single user post two answers for one question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165831/163250) | [Why is it possible to answer a question twice?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/174967/163250) | [Single person answer more than once for a question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186457/163250) | [Can I post more than one answer of a question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/224772/163250)

Answer (score 105):

When you have two distinct answers, it's better to post two different answers than to put them both into one answer.

Some questions will be multiple-answer types directly, like in Meta topics where aspects of features are wanted as feedback.  This allows the ones the community feels are the best/correct to float to the top.

Some computer languages have a lot of flexibility in how to solve any one problem, so by listing them both as separate answers (if **very distinct**) they can both be voted on by the community, and this will allow the better answer to float to the top.  It also allows the comment threads to be more focused on each answer.

If you put two very different answers in one, then one could be a great answer, and one could be a terrible way to do things, but the upvotes (or downvotes) on the good (or bad) answer will drag the other along with it to the top (or bottom).

Comment: only if they are radically and totally different answers, and even then I am not sure I agree.

Comment: Out of curiosity, Jeff, if you don't agree with answering a question twice, why does Stack Overflow let you?

Comment: All of the multiple answers I've given to questions have been for non-specific questions on SO, though on SU I've given distinct 'tips' or 'shortcuts' as different answers.  I can see though with some languages having multiple ways of doing it, putting both answers in so the community can vote on which is the 'best-practice' way of doing things.

Comment: chris, you have to click through a special confirmation dialog to add a second answer. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @Jeff - Not really. It means you admit that there may be a valid reason for someone to answer a question twice, which counteracts your argument here that you don't think there is a valid reason to answer a question twice.

Comment: I've posted twice to an answer (and got a * Answer badge for both of them), but it was one of those old-fashioned poll-type "fun" questions that we wouldn't tolerate these days, so I don't think it's a good example at all.

Comment: What do you think about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10309408/how-to-add-vertical-spacing-between-block-elements-but-not-top-and-bottom) question? Is it ok to post multiple answers on this, like I have done?

Comment: @Starx, I think those are fine as different answers, though you could also combine them as alternatives in one answer.  It might even boost the top answer more, since it will have more content and people will think it more valueable.

Comment: I disagree with "It's better to post two different answers, than to put them into one answer."  A single post with multiple approaches is more authoritative that multiple posts, if for no other reason than people like to read the headlines and might easily skip the 2nd or 3rd answer.

Comment: @JohnDibling, it's better because they will both get separate voting, so the better answer will float to the top.

Comment: I've only done this once, and on SU. Compare [answer 1](http://superuser.com/a/449293/144961) to [answer 2](http://superuser.com/a/449265/144961) (which was written first).

Comment: +1 I'm not sure if *completely different* can be defined well enough (consider different levels of voter's knowledge on subject) to serve as a rule-of-thumb.  As my subjective opinion from my understanding of SO, multiple answers lead to confusion since as both answerer and asker, I expect *the solution that worked* to be accepted, the act being proof that it did, even in (so often) cases when from the question it's not clear (yet?) which one is most relevant.

Comment: Also what I hate and happens to me is that I get 2-in-1 answer, part of it being right and the other wrong (by which I mean, not solving the problem asked), but still interesting enough not to be deleted -- now what?  Accept the wrong part?  Then how will such Q+A+A pair be evaluated as a duplicate?  IMO, final structure should be part of the communication, and that cannot be achieved without proper semantics.

Comment: @John Kugelman, this Meta works for all sites, some of which allow those.

Comment: Here's another neat example: JohnB's two answers on this graphic design question [How do I make an incomplete circle stroke for a donut chart?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/31286/how-do-i-make-an-incomplete-circle-stroke-for-a-donut-chart) - two good, very different techniques, offering different types of flexibility

Comment: @LanceRoberts not only is it good to post separate answers for voting purposes, but also for commenting.

Comment: also, answering twice could give you twice the added rep. (if both answers are equally good)

Comment: Do you think this answer is still good advice? I'm a little concerned about the way it seems to endorse poll questions (which we often close) as well as the degree to which it encourages splitting up answers on non-SO sites. I'm a mod on cooking, where it's pretty common for there to be a couple aspects of a question, and more than one good idea, and I feel like if people interpret "distinct answers" pretty literally, we'd end up with way too many answers and way too little organization.

Comment: I agree with your answer, and it's true that poll questions invite such answers. But it seems that new users read into it more than it's saying, namely that poll questions are welcome (and should be answered with multiple answers). Could you please indicate in some way that this is not the case and that in current policy, poll questions should not be answered at all? I'd edit it myself, but I don't want to make radical edits to your post. This won't make your answer any less valid, as there are other cases where multiple answers are still welcome.

Comment: @Jefromi, edited out polls, but I would think that on cooking questions you'd have a lot of different techniques to do one thing, and you'd want those in separate answers.  Being simplistic something like stew or baste or fry.  That way people could vote on which technique they thought was the proper way to do things.

Comment: @rumtscho, edited.

Comment: @LanceRoberts I see. I can tell you pretty confidently that in general we definitely don't want multiple answers on cooking. Yes, there are often a lot of facets or different ideas, but they're also often all connected, so it doesn't really make sense to split them up. It's much more useful to readers to have things presented in context in a well-organized way. It's also often true that the multiple parts of an answer aren't better or worse than each other, but simply *different* and all useful.

Comment: I too think you should remove or rephrase "Some questions will be multiple-answer types directly, like tips-and-tricks or best-practices" from your otherwise great answer because it seems to invite questions that are too broad for focussed Q&A.

Comment: @PolyGeo Yeh, it's a 7-year old answer, and things were different here then. I might massage it.

Comment: Let's say you 2 distinct solutions, and you write 2 answers. Then since technology changes, and we change, you can't recommend one of them any more, even though it already has reputation. Ordinarily in such cases you should edit your answer. But when you have two answers there is the risk that they'll become similar to one another.

Answer (score 29):

I have already had a couple of "real" (e.g. not a poll or fluff or humor) questions where I answered with 2 or even 3 solutions, explaining the reasons to pick each one. And i'm a relative newbie on SO (only 4k rep).

One place where this situation is especially likely to come true is Perl (aka ThereIsMoreThanOneWayToDoIt language).

While I usually squeeze all my ideas into a single post in such situations, I greatly appreciate the ability to NOT put them in one basket, so to speak - e.g. when I feel that posting one of the answers is education and adds to the site's useful content, yet the other one is "more deserving" (e.g. cuter/more elegant) and you don't want the up/down votes from one to affect the other.

Answer (score 8):

When they offer different approaches to the problem?¨

Sometimes one answer may be directly related with the problem the user is asking.

Other answer may be something that you suggest as an alternative.

For instance, *"How do I shoot my self in the foot with C++"*

1st answer ... .*First you do #define if while etc. etc*

2nd answer ... *Why use C++, you can use ( this, and that, and the other )*

There always can be two answer for the same question ( specially when is vague )

Comment: Why not just roll the alternatives into the same question and punctuate with subheadings?

Comment: @random - s/question/answer/;

Comment: so they can be voted on, so the best 'answers' will float to the top, not have one be voted on and drag the other with it.

Comment: @random: That's what I do most of the times. An answer and a complement/alternatives/workarounds. But when the answers are totally different, better is to post them separated. The first answer my solve directly the problem ( how to shoot your self in the foot ) the other may go either deeper, or in another direction or simply point something that on your experience is not what the user asked but what he needs ( like NOT shooting him self on the foot, when he can shoot someone else's foot in first place? )

Comment: @Lutz - Question/Answer slip crappy crappy. Darn it all to Beck.

Answer (score 3):

I can't think of a *good* reason for doing that, except for polls, which are not welcome (except occasionally on meta sites).

If you have two solutions to the same problem, post them in a single answer. Explain when you would use this solution and when you would use that solution. This is better than two separate answers that don't address when to use each solution. For example: “If you have version 1, do <this>. If you have version 2, you can use <this simpler solution> instead.”

Comment: I don't think it is possible to post only one answer when latter involves a lot of instructions. E.g. I have *four* answers posted to your question [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/56561/96277) and I honestly don't think I could post them as one or may be two without confusing the reader.

Comment: @Firelord I actually found your multiple answers, with some of them referencing others, a bit confusing. It would have been better to present a single answer with an introduction that summarizes each method and how you'd choose between them, and then a section for each method.

Answer (score 3):

Even though there are multiple ways to reach certain goals (I am thinking specifically of some programming questions using Python, SQL,...), I prefer to post only one answer per post.

However, in my answers, frequently, I share multiple of ways to achieve those goals using various methods. One can even amplify the answer later on.

Will leave below the structure that I tend to use for those questions:

---

**Intro** (Optional)

- Option 1 - some info on the option
- Option 2 - some info on the option
- ...

---

**Option 1**

[Add content]

---

**Option 2**

[Add content]

---

**Notes:** (Optional)

- Note 1
- Note 2
- ...

Answer (score -7):

If it is possible for a question to have two valid answers from the same person, the odds are high that it's a bad question.

(in other words, it's a poll question.)

In general there should be one answer per person per question; if you need to amplify your answer, **edit it!**

Comment: Jeff - I fear I must point out a counter-example for you. In 2 words: "Perl" questions. I can frequently think of 5 different ways of answering a given question before even getting my breakfast, to paraphrase from Alice.

Comment: P.S. However, I agree that, with some exceptions, the practice of posting multiple answers is Not A Good Thing, and therefore highly approve of SO's solution (allow but add extra hoops to do so).

Comment: Sux - I just lamented that about Sinan's answer no longer than 3 hrs ago

Comment: Why does it *matter* whether the two answers are from the *same person*? Who cares?

Comment: @DVK if all 5 solutions are equally good and sufficiently brief, I think it makes more sense to post them all in a single comprehensive, definitive answer.

Comment: @rob - because the collective wisdome very well might decide that 1 is outstanding and "best", 2 are good, 1 is meh, and 1 is really really bad. They need a way to differentiate

Comment: @rob - also see comment from  Lance Roberts Oct 8 '09 at 22:43 on another answer here

Comment: @DVK I disagree. If part of an answer is really great, you'll almost certainly get at least one upvoted comment patting you on the back for that solution. If part of an answer is actually *bad* (as opposed to *not good*), the community *should* tell you why in the comments so you can remove it or note in your answer that it is not recommended. Perhaps if each answer is very long or if the site demands one solution per answer, it makes sense to post them separately. Otherwise you're just trying to turn the question into a poll or popularity contest.

Comment: @rob - the goal isn't to get votes. It's to differentiate good from bad approaches

Comment: @DVK I didn't say anything about increasing your upvotes by splitting up multiple solutions into separate answers, but I do think some people will try to game the system in that way. As I said, when someone points out that one of your approaches is especially good or bad via a comment, you can edit your answer accordingly to differentiate good from bad. It isn't necessary to split them into physically separate answers. Presumably if you're knowledgeable enough to provide a really great solution, you won't intentionally include a horrible solution without stating that it's a horrible solution.

Comment: @rob Sure, but what happens if someone who isn't very knowledgeable about the topic finds that upvoted, multiple-answers-in-one post? How can they know which solution is (deemed) best? I.e. how do the votes distribute among the different solutions? Assuming some expert will always come by and "correct" any bad solutions and "elevate" the best solution in that post via comments *before* anyone less knowledgeable sees the post seems like wishful thinking.