# Why is it possible to answer a question twice?

Tags: feature-request, answers, multiple-answers

You normally answer a question and you have the opportunity to answer again. The second time, a message is shown suggesting the use of the **edit** tool, but I think it's kind of wrong. I mean, if you answer something and then you want to say anything else you know that you must use **edit**.

Why not disable the answer button if you already have an answer?

Comment: Because you may have another answer that resolves the problem in a completely different way.

Comment: But what happen if you just say that you have two ways to answer the question? It's too hard?

Comment: @Castiblanco then people can't vote separately on each suggestion, which they might want to do.

Comment: Josh, Pekka: Wouldn't such question be non-constructive?

Comment: @Chichiray Consider someone wanting to read all the data from an xml file and process it in C#. There are many different options on how to handle that task.

Comment: That depends on the question - some questions have a lot of sub questions, which may be answered in different ways (and at different times)

Comment: @Josh: Wouldn't such question be overly broad? But yes, I see what you're getting at. I've always just covered all options in 1 answer. This has always worked quite good so far.

Comment: @Chichiray: In theory and first glance, yes. But "specific programming problems" can often be solved in multiple ways. That's different to asking questions which *encourage* multiple answers (polls etc.).

Comment: @Chichiray Normally I would too but depending on the scenario I could see how it could be useful to differentiate between which one the community recommends via the number of upvotes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, people should be able to post multiple answers if they actually have different suggestions. This way the different suggestions can be voted on separately.

Comment: +1 I see what you did there.

Comment: Please note that it makes sense on meta discussions, not on constructive questions :)

Comment: Argh, the 60 seconds rate limit for additional answers is annoying.

Comment: Ooooh, so it's to get double the reputation...

Comment: Can't vote up your answer because of rep shortage. But epic!

Comment: @Chichiray Not only Meta discussions, sometimes it makes sense on the main site as well. It's rare but it happens ([Code Golf.SE](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) is a good example where multiple answers from the same author are common).

Comment: [I was searching the same question where you answered twice!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165831/187824)

Comment: @hims056 I've done this before? Crap, I guess you can't expect new tricks from an old dog ;)

Comment: @BlahBlahGrabblesnackers It's certainly a good way to get double the rep (assuming the answers are good, otherwise you'll probably end up losing double the rep). That said, I'm quite the failed rep whore, I posted both answers after I had hit the rep cap for the day.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables If your answers are bad, you *lose* double the reputation.