# Do not group together answers to the same question in user page stats

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, answers, profile-page

I recently gave two different answers to [a cw question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245196/c-urban-myths) (because it was basically asking for a list of independent items, of which I happened to provide two).

I feel that it adds no value to have the two answers grouped in the user stats page, for the following reasons:

- It adds unnecessary complexity to the answer list.
- The answer list is a handy collection of links to my answers, and this policy suddenly hides one of them.
- Answer scores are most useful when seen individually. If one of my answers has a score of +8 and the other has -2, I want to see that -2 to check if I can improve anything. I won't see that if I see a +6.

I suggest to display answers in separate rows, something like:

- **8**  Question Title (answer #1)
- **-2** Question Title (answer #2)

**Update:** There is a workaround that lets you see these data "decoupled". It is a [search for your posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3a35135&tab=newest).

Comment: This feature request seems to be status-completed. However I am not a moderator so I cannot put it in such state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if I agree with this; multiple answers to the same question are still one logical whole -- in that they are all *answers to the very same question*.

Giving people special "props" for one answer versus another on the *same* question means they'll be incentivized to compete with their own answers and one-up themselves.

We really would prefer that people edit their answers and provide only one good-better-best answer to a question, [except in exceptional circumstances](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25209/what-is-the-official-etiquette-on-answering-a-question-twice).

Comment: You are basically saying (based also on http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25209/what-is-the-official-etiquette-on-answering-a-question-twice/25211#25211) that the two answers I gave shouldn't be there in the first place, because the question shouldn't even exist - it's a poll. This seems to be an edge situation in SO for which there is not a definitive answer, since these questions _actually_ exist and people are clearly interested in them (that particular question has a score of +55 and has been viewed 2,102 times in one day, and my two answers have +13 and +11 respectively).

Comment: @daniel it's fine for there to be edge conditions, but it is not fine for us to *encourage* these edge conditions.