# Two answers on one question doesn't work right

Tags: feature-request, answers, profile-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do not group together answers to the same question in user page stats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39097/do-not-group-together-answers-to-the-same-question-in-user-page-stats)

if you go to [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/69742/earlz) and sort my answers by votes you'll see at the top

```
What Features Do You Want To See in .NET 5/C# 5? (2)
```

Apparently this 2 means 2 answers and the vote count beside it is a cumulative vote across the two answers(35=38-2). My question is why not just break this apart into two separate entries in the answers box? Why are they joined together like this?

And the more annoying thing is that when I click it I go to a random answer. Then I have to figure out where the other answer is. There is no link provided for it.

Comment: Feel the pain for answering not a real question!

Comment: `35=38-2`. [LIES!](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&q=38-2&aq=f&aqi=g5g-ms1g-m3&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=)

Comment: @Michael ah good point. the shown score makes no sense then.