# Duplicate recent activity entries

Tags: support, recent-activity

[image: first and second entries on the "Recent Activity" page look identical to each other]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is correct; you have two answers on that question, both at +1:

- [4564563](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564545/how-can-i-build-the-regex-to-match-a-string-not-containing-au-1/4564563#4564563)
- [4564676](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564545/how-can-i-build-the-regex-to-match-a-string-not-containing-au-1/4564676#4564676)

Comment: Arg, of course. Silly me!

Comment: @marcog, see also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39097/do-not-group-together-answers-to-the-same-question-in-user-page-stats.