# Weird behavior of community wiki answers after migration

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, community-wiki, migrated-questions

I stumbled upon [this user profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/15541/leppie?tab=answers) here on Meta, as you can see [this is](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60445/is-it-ok-to-post-multiple-answers-to-a-question/60446#60446) one of his answers.

The answer is in old question that was migrated here to Meta from Stack Overflow.

The answer appears to be all normal including "answered Dec 12 '08 at 3:37" appearing properly and the user name displayed to the right. **However**, clicking on either of those leads to the [Revisions page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/60446/revisions) of the answer where things goes funky:

> > [image]

No username whatsoever. Same happens for all answers on that question.

What's going on?

Comment: +1 for that freehand question mark ;)

Comment: @hims056 yeah, I'm good with my hands what can I say? :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In short: Migrations used to suck, we've made them substantially more robust over time.  Something from that long ago didn't have all the data carried along with it, that's since been resolved.

A while ago several of us pretty much completely re-wrote how migrations work.  It used to be a cross-database Linq2SQL affair which resulted in the wrong user having their rep updated in an edge case.

When we *finally* found that bug (no kidding: logging every rep change for a few builds, that one was *crazy*) we said screw it and re-wrote the thing as an API call.  What happens now is we serialize everything that's needed into one protobuf object and make an API call to the destination site.  That site then handles all the inserting/creation that's needed for the question, returning the new URL for the old site to point to.

While not specific to this bug, that re-write, by nature, fixed lots of issues like this.  I just confirmed locally a user name would appear in this case if the migration happened today.

Comment: Thanks! So you say the post I linked to is a lost case? Not that it really matters, just wondering. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - yeah, fixing these up cross-database/cross-site would be quite the insane adventure...more important fish frying at the moment so I can't see this ever being a priority really.

Comment: Fair enough Nick, go bake those fish! ;)