# When should one add another answer instead of editing one's already posted?

Tags: discussion, answers, edits

When is it reasonable/recommended to add another answer when I have already added one? My doubt comes from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6266856) that I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6266856#6267025) although I find later that the question was not complete. I found a way to solve the problem and was going to post it when I got the "add another answer" question.

So, should I post a new answer in this case or edit the somewhat faulty one? Better yet, when is it appropriate to post another answer?

Comment: See also [When should I add another answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/125752/178505)

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25209/what-is-the-official-etiquette-on-answering-a-question-twice

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If your edit is clarifying something in your existing answer, just edit that answer to update it.

If you have multiple *independent* solutions for the same problem, then post them as separate answers so they can be voted/accepted/discussed independently.  One might be great, and the other might be stupid.  Best not to lump them together, eh?