# If a user upvotes answers to a question and I have multiple answers there, it is hardly serial voting

Tags: discussion, serial-voting

Today I had "serial upvoting" reversed and lost 40 rep. But it is hardly can be called serial voting: seems that a user was voting for requests he liked in [this recent post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249951/help-us-test-the-shiny-new-user-activity-page-plus-a-bunch-of-new-features) and also voted for 4 of my 17 (yeah, I have many :D) feedback-answers to this question. It would be conspicuous if the user would vote all the 17 of my answers, but he didn't (and even in this case it is *one* question, so theoretically, a user can vote all the answers, but can just run out of votes if there are more than 40 answers).

How can it be serial voting?

It was reversed today and therefore I have rep capped at just 160 :(

Comment: Related: [The vote fraud script breaks legitimate polling questions - A serial downvoter's lament](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/150180)

Comment: That person was probably me.  I wasn't thinking about possible serial voting at all.  (And today I voted for both this question and your answer on the question Raincoat linked...)

Comment: I don't really think this case warrants a change in their decision. It's still extremely rare for something legitimate like this to happen, and it's not like you don't have a plethora of votes on those posts to counter the "serial" votes that got reversed.