# Will voting on many community wiki questions from the same user trigger serial voting?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki, serial-voting

Over on [scifi.meta.SE](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13005/ways-to-improve-and-promote-science-fiction-and-fantasy), there is a question with lots of answers by the same person which are options for users to vote on.

In [this comment](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13005/ways-to-improve-and-promote-science-fiction-and-fantasy?noredirect=1#comment45681_13005) by [Rand al'Thor](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/users/31394/rand-althor), Rand warns that voting quickly on lots of the answers may trigger the [serial voting system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829/353213):

> General note to voters here: since this thread contains many answers by the same person, if you vote on all of them too quickly, your votes may be invalidated by the system (thinking it's "serial voting").

However, since community wikis don't earn the user any rep, **would multiple quick votes on *community wiki* answers count as serial upvoting?**

From the [wiki page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829/353213) on serial voting, the mechanics are secret - is it possible to get any details on this?

> Every night around 03:00 UTC, a voting fraud detection script is run that looks for patterns such as these. It basically looks for users who have voted on another user's posts many times. The threshold number is fairly low within a given amount of time (the exact mechanics are kept secret). When the system detects this pattern, all of the votes cast from that user to the user affected are reversed, and a "voting corrected" event is added to the affected user's reputation history to indicate what has occurred.

Comment: I don't think it will, the wiki says *It basically looks for users who have voted on another user's posts many times*. Since the CW's belong to community which isn't really a user  I don't think they are affected

Comment: [here is a workaround](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238712/165773) "supplement poll with counter-vote answer(s)..."

Comment: @gnat it does if that has been implemented.

Comment: @gnat boo, `status-declined`... I guess it'll have to do, though I didn't see community wiki at first blush. But if they declined fixing things there, they probably won't fix this either.