# Suspicious / serial upvoting - flag it, or raise it on meta?

Tags: support, serial-voting, policy

[This user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1647411/joe-regan) received an upvote on every one of their eleven questions (and two of their answers), during a four minute window on November 14th. Three of those questions are closed, two have a negative score, and a further four would have a negative score if not for the upvotes in question.

Two days later, the user offered bounties on two of their questions, taking their rep down to a single digit.

What's the appropriate course of action here? The upvotes are clearly suspicious, but flagging each one individually seems like a waste of moderators' time. I've done a quick search for "suspicious voting activity" here on meta, but didn't find anything that suggested what to do in this situation.

Comment: Suspicious looking indeed. The "arbitrary rep change" event is pretty rare as well.

Comment: Looks pretty obvious what's going on here. The user is so desperate to get an answer that (s)he made a sockpuppet to get enough rep to put some bounties. (either a sockpuppet or some other person)

Comment: @Mysticial: It would have to be multiple sockpuppets for those votes not to get reversed by the system. What's funny is that on the 15th the system automatically reversed a downvote at the 03:00 check but not all the upvotes.

Comment: @animuson The serial voting scripts are definitely time-sensitive in some way. I've seen it triggered in [as few as 6 upvotes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131710/should-this-be-picked-up-by-the-vote-fraud-detecting-algorithm). Yet there have been at least two occasions where I've been serially upvoted with more than 10 and not reversed. But in those cases, the votes were all on my top answers and were separated by several minutes each. In this case, there's no time between the votes - so the script *should've* picked them up.

Comment: @AnnaLear thanks! Not that you need the rep, but if you made that an answer I'd accept it for the sake of closure ... and, yes, I think I probably *am* borderline OCD ;-)

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus I always need the rep. Especially the very meaningful meta rep. =)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Flagging for a moderator and leaving a note is still the right way to go. You don't have to flag every post. Just flag one and describe the situation in as much detail as you can and/or feel like.

Reporting things like this on meta usually just leads to speculation and might actually get missed by the people who have the access to the tools needed to fully investigate and take action.

Speaking of which... don't worry about it for this case now; I'm looking into it. :)