# Can I give two answers to a question having two problems

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, multiple-answers

Last evening a question was asked I replied and it was accepted.

Then the OP edited the question and asked a related question, however that can stand alone with some meaning.

So, Can  I give two different answers or, I should edit the answer and append the answer of the second question?

Comment: If the edited question is *that* different that it warrants two separate answers, it should probably be rolled back and he should ask a separate question.

Comment: @animuson: His second question was an extension to the first one.

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with posting multiple answers to the same question if they're different solutions or approaches. However, the way you describe it, it really sounds like a chameleon question so giving you general advice doesn't seem like it'd be helpful here. It'd be better to give advice based on your specific situation (which requires a link to the question).

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25209/what-is-the-official-etiquette-on-answering-a-question-twice

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how much the question was edited. If it was just an extension off the first post but still closely related to the original question then you should edit/update your current answer. If it's off-topic from the original question then OP should post a new question. I would attempt to improve your current answer unless your answers are two different approaches.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, but I'd say you would *rarely* need to. Bear in mind that the user can only accept one answer, and the fullest answer to address the OPs problem(s) would be best marked as the correct answer - so, you can benefit from the system in terms of gaining rep (even this is a dubious possibility) but you're potentially contributing to breaking the system simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

If the two problems are *distinct*, then it's better to encourage the OP to create a new question, providing appropriate context.

Example:

> Why won't my code execute this logic path?  Could its performance be
>   improved?

If the two problems are *closely related*, then it's fine to answer them in the same question.

Example:

> Why won't my code execute this logic path?  Do I have to add another
>   check at the beginning of my loop to get it there?