# Can I post more than one answer to a question?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, answers, multiple-answers

I'm asking because of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22283385/3330969).  I have already provided an answer and I have another way to achieve the solution. I want to add both answers.

Can I do that or are there any consequences for this?

Comment: Yes, you can and should post another answer, if you think it is helpful.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply :)

Comment: Note that if your answers are solving _two different problems_, as opposed to being two _separate solutions to one problem_, that's [a stong indication that the question should be closed instead of answered](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222885/fastest-gun-answering-generally-same-question-twice/222887#comment725658_222887).

Comment: Also note that [your answer being incorrect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22283385/matching-all-the-rows-returned-by-a-nested-select-statement#comment33857443_22286014) is not a good reason to add another answer (at least not without deleting the first); the proper response to that is editing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As long as your solutions are distinct and self-contained, you're welcome to post each solution as its own answer if you would rather do that than consolidate both of them into, or replace one with the other within, a single answer.

You should not use multiple answers when they are two parts to one solution.

Comment: ok @BoltClock's a Unicorn i'll keep that in mind and will answer accordingly :) but in case of edit is votes on that answer will persist or they'll go away?

Comment: @Vikas Editing doesn't make votes go away. However, it _lets_ people undo or reverse their vote (for better or worse): votes are locked in after 5 minutes, but _if the post gets edited_, your vote gets unlocked.

Comment: ok i know about the locking of the votes and unlocking when i edit but for how much time the votes are unlocked after edit?

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can but it would be good if you have posted one answer and the second answer you thought is good, you can edit your first answer and post the second answer inside the first answer.

Comment: If they are fundamentally different approaches, they should be separate answers.

Comment: Yes if they are fundamentally different and distinct solution. What if they just give an alternate way. IMO it would be great to merge the two answer within one.

Comment: but in case of edit is votes on that answer will persist or they'll go away?

Comment: The votes will be persisted :-).