# Why can you not answer a question more than once?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answers

When you have a question, and you have multiple suggestions, you have to put it in the same answer. Why can't SE sites allow you to answer a question more than once?

Comment: You can do that??

Comment: Who says you can't answer more than once? You do get a warning asking you if that's what you really want to do but you can proceed.

Comment: First, you can add multiple answers, but generally having multiple suggestions means that you actually don't have proper answer and that you are just wild guessing, which usually also means that question is unclear and close worthy. It is better to avoid answering such questions.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25209/what-is-the-official-etiquette-on-answering-a-question-twice

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some sites - notably Software Recommendations actually encourage this in some circumstances.

Practically though, in most situations, unless you're aware of dramatically different *solutions* (not mere suggestions), that the community at large may weigh differently, you shouldn't need to.

As such a prohibition on multiple answers is *by* the community, not by the mechanics of the site.

I may or may not, sometimes abuse this on site metas as a poor mans polling system.